# Magento observer event when user has submitted their billing details

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, observers

I am trying to find a Magento frontend observer event that will trigger on the 'onepage checkout' page when the user has entered their '**Billing**' details and clicked the submit button.

I am using Magento 1.7 and have come across this site which has a list of events, however I am unsure which this would be?
http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

Can anyone suggest anything or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked observer worked:

```
checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method
```

Answer (score 1):

The data from the billing address is sent to `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveBillingAction` so you can use `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_savebilling`

Then you can access in your observer the data sent through post  like this

```
$post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
```

But this may not fit your needs. If it doesn't then please explain what you want to do ehn you captrure the data.

Comment: thanks Marius that looks useful, might take awhile to test it out though still getting to grips with Magento - will this be ok with version 1.7.x?